# I am trying to add a progress bar on my android app to show as the application loads data, using Ecplise,

Tags: android, eclipse, progress-bar, loading, progressdialog

I would ideally like this progress bar to run as a pop-up dialogue box - like a loading bar... as the user clicks on the icon to run the app... then once the app loads it disappears.

I have been researching ways of doing this but struggling to find a working solution... Any help would be great

Comment: What have you tried? What exactly are you loading? Are you using an Async Task? Or are you loading everything in the UI thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use an Android [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html), you have two choices:

```
<ProgressBar
    style="@android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="true" />
```

This will provide you with a spinner that will loop forever. Then you just show and hide this as required.

The alternative to large in scope for SO. The principle however, is you get the following:

- Size of data to download
- Current speed of client data transfer

To calculate the total time remaining for the download. You then use a handler to post periodic updates to a traditional linear progressBar and this will give you a progress bar that tracks the download.
However as you've seen from everything MS have ever done, this calculation is tricky as connection speeds vary constantly.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Declare new ProgressBar:

```
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
```

In your onCreate() method:

```
mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(YOURACTIVITY);
mProgressDialog.setMessage("");
mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
```

Show your dialog when you want:

```
mProgressDialog.show();
mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Add your progress:

```
mProgressDialog.setProgress(INT PROGRESS);
```

Dismiss your dialog when you want:

```
mProgressDialog.dismiss();
```